# How to use placeholder for controller class name in ViewReolver

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I want to put controller name (class name or bean name) as dir name when SpringMVC is resolving view name.
I defined prefix param in `UrlBasedViewResolver` like `/WEB-INF/admin/${controller}/`, but it doesn't work, of course.

```xml
<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/admin/${controller}/"/>
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView"/>
</bean>
```

Obviously, it doesn't work because `UrlBasedViewResolver` just simple attach view prefix to view name (like `view.setUrl(getPrefix() + viewName + getSuffix());`).

What's the easiest way to implement this issue?

Or what's the easiest way to get controller name in resolver to overried `buildView` method in `UrlBasedViewResolver` subclass?

Comment: What is a "controller name"?  Bean name?  Class name? Path name?

Comment: @skaffman, it's not necessary. But class name would better.

Comment: What do you mean, "not necessary"?  Please be specific, and update your question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to create a [`HandlerInterceptor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-handlermapping-interceptor) and modify view name property of `ModelAndView` in its `postHandle()` method (it's invoked after execution of controller but before rendering a view). This method also receives instance of the controller as `handle`.